# DataAnnotation for checking if the integer is not a negative value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a `Quantity` column in my table in SQL Server 2008. But I want to write a data annotation in my asp.net mvc web application that checks if the entered value is greater than or equal to 1? So can anyone tell me which data annotation to use?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Does [range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute?view=net-8.0) work?

```
[Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Value should be greater than or equal to 1")]
```

Answer (score 0):

To show the field name and the value in the message you can use

```
[Range(0.0, Double.PositiveInfinity, ErrorMessage = "The field {0} should be greater than {1}")]
public double MyFieldName { get; set; }
```